# Salesforce Trigger Handler Framework - Testing the Trigger

Tags: unit-test

I'm looking at implementing a trigger handler framework and I understand the benefits of separation, dispatching to helpers from the handler, etc.

What hasn't been obvious looking over the materials from the various frameworks, is how to test the trigger if the handler calls a helper which executes a callout in an async process?

Does the triggers own test class need to set a mock so it is in the call stack if the helpers handler attempts to callout?

Meaning, the mock is established in 2-3 places:
a) in the helper's own test class
b) in the handler's test class to cover the helper invocation
c) in the trigger's test class to cover the lines that invoke the handler that does b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a typical trigger framework, the framework has a way to be selectively disabled. This way, when you're just trying to set up data for the main test, you can "turn off" the triggers to avoid having to include extra dependencies like a callout mock that you're not trying to test, and to reduce both execution time and governor limits usage. If you're using a framework correctly, your trigger should have a single line of code that calls the framework, and so you're only interested in getting 100% coverage by triggering the trigger, and that's it. Of course, you may choose to have other tests to make sure you're not exceeding governor limits.

Comment: Agree with @sfdcfox but also at the place where you are making a callout, you could just check if the Test is running or real scenario is running to avoid callout during test class run.

Comment: @salesforcewithfunforce I was considering this using Trigger.isExecuting but I thought that would be in the handler vs the helper executing the callout.

Comment: @sfdcfox Is this specifically about hitting Salesforce limits during test execution? I was not sure at first glance but then it made sense

Comment: @sfdcfox is this an example of where a simple static variable (bypassHandlerExecution) on the handler can be set in the call of the Trigger Test Class to bypassHandlerExecution = true.  Or is there a general recommendation to combine testing Trigger.isExecuting && Test.isRunningTest() to bypass the handler?  I'm familiar with seeing the cmt type off switches before, but that seems excessive going to the metadata API in a test class.

Comment: @salesforcewithfunforce I have a strong philosophy against Using any Test features in live code whenever possible. In an ideal world, the live code should not know if it's running live or in a test.

Comment: @almc Yes, a simple static variable would suffice. The CMDT stuff is just a way to turn off triggers in a prod environment if things go wrong. Consider it an emergency switch to disable some functionality in exchange for fixing production until a deployment can be made. In my own framework, each trigger and operation type can be independently toggled to focus on specific code I want to cover.

Answer (score 1):

A more architected solution would be to do all your callouts using an async manager framework wherein the async request is written to a custom "command" or "async request" object and then an "async manager" executes these.  Then the test methods merely need to turn off the async manager

Examples of "async managers" abound, I'll cite two

- Dan Appleman's [Advanced Apex Programming](https://advancedapex.com/) book, latest edition, chapter "Going Async"
- @PhilW [sf-async-callout](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout) GitHub repo

I've used the former for years (it came out before @Philw 's solution).

This approach has some especially useful benefits - the ability to replay the async callouts in case they fail for whatever reason (as well as a generalized notification approach to log / alert)

Comment: Also a decent option. I wrote an async manager back in 2014 for my employer back then. It had the extra capability of being toggled on/off with custom settings (cmdt didn't exist then) as well as a rpm (records per minute, lol) setting to avoid swamping downstream servers.